# Dynamically update a html element value based on h1

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

Right, I have a problem which I am struggling to get my head around.

On an aspx master page (procedure.master.aspx) I have the following element:

```
<Tags>
    <wbc:Tag Value="234"></wbc:Tag>
</Tags>
```

what I want to be able to do is change the **VALUE** of this depending on the page content (procedures.aspx which calls the master) i.e. if `H1` contains `"FOO"` then Tag `Value="BAR"` etc.

The TAG value is sent to a stored procedure returning XML based on the content of the page.

Not a javascript GURU so open to any suggestions with Javascript (not JQuery) or VB.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would not mind doing this on the server, use the code below. It worked for me:

In your HTML add the following:

```
   <h1 runat="server" id="header1">Foo</h1>
    <div runat="server" id="tag1"></div>
```

and in the code behind page load:

```
        If header1.InnerText = "Foo" Then
            tag1.InnerText = "BAR"
        Else
            tag1.InnerText = ""
        End If
```

or (for the sake of clarity)

In your HTML add the following:

```
   <h1 runat="server" id="header1">Foo</h1>
   <Tags>
       <wbc:Tag Value="234" runat="server" id="tag1"></wbc:Tag>
   </Tags>
```

and in the code behind page load:

```
        If header1.InnerText = "Foo" Then
            tag1.Value= "BAR"
        Else
            tag1.Value= ""
        End If
```

Comment: A nice simple JS free way of doing it. Great idea @Simua - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should work if you have jQuery. This code also assumes you give your wbc:Tag element an id, in this case "myElement".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $("h1#elementName").text();
    if (text == "FOO");
        $("#myElement").attr("Value", "BAR");
});
```

As you can see, this will read the content of the H1 element on load. Is that what you wanted? Or can the content of the element be changed dynamically?

Comment: Hi @martingo89 thanks for your solution. I can give the <wbc:tag> an ID however as the site is already JS heavy for other functions I am trying to avoid adding jqeury into the mix. Although I may be able to do something based on your snippet. Still open to other ideas though.